# How do I export multiple numpy arrays to a text file with a specific delimiter and line breaks?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following three numpy arrays in my python file:

```
array([[    1,     1,    14,     1,    15],
       [    2,     1,    14,     1,    13],
       [    3,     1,    15,     1,    13]]) 

array([[   1,    1,    1,   13],
       [   2,    1,    1,   14],
       [   3,    1,    1,   15]])

array([[  10,    2,    4,   17],
       [  11,    3,    6,   20],
       [  12,    4,    6,   21]])
```

I am trying to output these in one text file with spaces and words in between them. So the output would look like this:

```
ListA

1 1 14 1 15
2 1 14 1 13
3 1 15 1 13

ListB

1 1 1 13
2 1 1 14
3 1 1 15

ListC

10 2 4 17
11 3 6 20
12 4 6 21
```

These arrays are thousands of rows long, so it has to be scalable. Right now, I am just using numpy's save to text command and manually adding the spaces and headers in between the arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually adding'?  WIth text editor, or separate write calls between the `savetxt` calls?  What's wrong with what you are doing?  Is the resulting file usable?

Comment: I export each array into a text file, and then paste it into the result file. Then I add the line breaks and headers such as ListA, ListB, and ListC. The file is usable, however I have several arrays of several thousand rows each, so it takes a long time to do this manually. I was wondering if a command existed where I could print it to a file with python and the line breaks, headers, and " " delimiter.

Comment: You can open a file in write mode, and call `savetxt` with that (rather than a filename), and use ordinary python file writes to write the spacer lines.  Read `savetxt` docs to see what it accepts as file.  Read up on python text fike writes.

Comment: You can open a file in write mode, and call `savetxt` with that (rather than a filename), and use ordinary python file writes to write the spacer lines.  Read `savetxt` docs to see what it accepts as file.  Read up on python text fike writes.

Comment: Thanks! I was unfamiliar with the python saving commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in my comments:

```
In [48]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    ...:     f.write('ListA\n\n')
    ...:     np.savetxt(f, np.ones((3,4),int), fmt='%d')
    ...:     f.write('\nListB\n\n')
    ...:     np.savetxt(f, np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), fmt='%d')
    ...:     f.write('\nListC\n\n')
    ...:     np.savetxt(f, np.array([[1.234, 4.234,.34]]), fmt='%f')
```

produces:

```
In [49]: cat test.txt
ListA

1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1

ListB

0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11

ListC

1.234000 4.234000 0.340000
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import re

txt = '''
array([[    1,     1,    14,     1,    15],
       [    2,     1,    14,     1,    13],
       [    3,     1,    15,     1,    13]]) 

array([[   1,    1,    1,   13],
       [   2,    1,    1,   14],
       [   3,    1,    1,   15]])

array([[  10,    2,    4,   17],
       [  11,    3,    6,   20],
       [  12,    4,    6,   21]])
'''

txt = txt.replace('array([[', 'ListA\n', 1)
txt = txt.replace('array([[', 'ListB\n', 1)
txt = txt.replace('array([[', 'ListC\n', 1)
txt = re.sub('[\[\]\),]', '', txt)
txt = re.sub(' +', ' ', txt)
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
ListA
 1 1 14 1 15
 2 1 14 1 13
 3 1 15 1 13

ListB
 1 1 1 13
 2 1 1 14
 3 1 1 15

ListC
 10 2 4 17
 11 3 6 20
 12 4 6 21
```